# Reading data into application memory from a buffer that was populated using two different buffers

Tags: c, opengl

I am trying (as an excercise) to read data into application memory from a buffer that was populated using two different buffers that themselves were populated from application memory.

Here's how I try to achieve it:

```
// Two arrays that contatain Vertex data that will be used to populate two different buffers
static const GLfloat positions[] = {
    -1, -1, 0, 1,
     1, -1, 0, 1,
     1,  1, 0, 1,
    -1,  1, 0, 1
};

static const GLfloat colors[] = {
    1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1
};

// The buffer object that will be populated by using two other buffers.
// After it will be populated with the data,
// we will try to read it into Application memory and use it to render a square.
GLuint vbo;

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

//Usage hint is GL_STATIC_COPY since we will populate the buffer with data copied from OpenGL buffers
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(positions) + sizeof(colors), nullptr, GL_STATIC_COPY);

// The buffers that will be populated with the data coming from the arrays positions and colors respectively
GLuint pvbo, cvbo;

glGenBuffers(1, &pvbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, pvbo);
glBufferData(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, sizeof(positions), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &cvbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, cvbo);
glBufferData(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Copying the data from the buffer pvbo into the first part of the buffer vbo
glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, pvbo);
glCopyBufferSubData(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 0, sizeof(positions));

// Copying the data from the buffer cvbo into the second part of the buffer vbo
glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, cvbo);
glCopyBufferSubData(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(positions), sizeof(colors));

//Now we will read back the data from the buffer vbo into Application memory and printf it
GLfloat* readback = (GLfloat*)malloc(sizeof(positions) + sizeof(colors));

glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(positions) + sizeof(colors), readback);

for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(positions) + sizeof(colors)) / sizeof(GLfloat); i++)
    printf("%.1f ", readback[i]);
putchar('\n');

    ...

    // After that I setup the VAO and I use the buffer to render some colored square by using glDrawArrays()
```

Everything works as expected and I get the following line printed to console:

```
-1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 -1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 -1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

And the colored square is rendered on screen.

---

The point is that I get several warnings when I enable debugging (i.e. call `glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT)`). Here's the list of warnings I get on an NVIDIA GPU (GeForce 525M):

```
(1) OpenGL:Other[LOW] (131188): Buffer usage warning: Analysis of buffer object 2 (bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB) usage indicates that CPU is consuming buffer object data.  The usage hint supplied with this buffer object, GL_STATIC_COPY, is inconsistent with this usage pattern.  Try using GL_STREAM_READ_ARB, GL_STATIC_READ_ARB, or GL_DYNAMIC_READ_ARB instead.

(2) OpenGL:Performance[MED] (131186): Buffer performance warning: Buffer object 2 (bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, usage hint is GL_STATIC_COPY) is being copied/moved from VIDEO memory to DMA CACHED memory.
```

When I change the usage of the **vbo** buffer that is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER binding point from GL_STATIC_COPY to GL_STATIC_READ as specified in the warnings above, I get another warning:

```
OpenGL:Other[LOW] (131188): Buffer usage warning: BufferData for buffer 2 was called with <usage> set to GL_STATIC_READ.
```

---

I am following the OpenGL Red Book 8<sup>th</sup> edition and it says on page 100:

> Of course, it is possible to use glGetBufferSubData() to simply read
>   back data that you previously put into the buffer object

But unfortunately it doesn't show any example of how to do it.

Comment: The buffer usage hint is a *hint*; you can read from and write to a buffer created with any hint, it just might not be as fast as it could be. I don't think there is a hint for writing data to the buffer and reading it back, because that's generally not a useful thing to do.

Comment: @immibis Thanks for the explanation.